# Examples of the Kaluza-Klein dimensional reduction method

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, compactification, kaluza-klein

I am looking for references or articles that apply or explain how to apply the dimensional reduction method to known metrics such as Minkowski, Schwarzschild, Kerr, etc. The references I found generally do so in a general way and I can't quite assimilate what happens in more particular or simple cases. Could someone please guide me or recommend a resource? I am currently applying the method to, for example, Minkowski but I would like to compare it with some resource

Comment: I know this article by Marina Huerta https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.00294

Comment: To clarify: by “dimensional reduction method” you mean a solution generating technique?

Comment: @A.V.S. Yes. I am interested in the process of compactifying along, for example, the $\phi$ direction in a 4-dimensional metric and generating new solutions.

Comment: I think you are conflating two distinct techniques. One: we start with 5d vacuum solution and reduce along some Killing vector field with a twist (e.g. $B ∂_\phi+ ∂_5$) and obtain 4d solution in Einstein-Maxwell-dilaton theory. Two: Ernst solution generating method, where dimensional reduction of the seed from 4d to 2d is only the first step followed by some sort of Ehlers/Harrison-like transformation (and the last step would be uplifting the new reduced solution back into 4d).

Comment: @A.V.S. You're right and I'm sorry if I didn't express myself clearly. I am referring to Ernst's solution generation method. I did not find references where they apply it to cases like Minkowski to obtain Melvin's universe for example and I cannot understand how after doing the entire procedure, return to four dimensions. Do you know any references?

Comment: The ch. 34 of the book *Exact solutions of Einstein's field equations* (CUP, 2009) is a good starting point.  Specifically for Minkowski seed the original ref. is [Hauser&Ernst](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.524180).

Comment: @A.V.S. Thank you very much for the articles. I was unaware of the paper you mention and in fact, days ago I asked [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/797657/adding-a-magnetic-field-to-a-flat-metric-with-kaluza-kleins-dimensional-reducti) where I show a bit of the procedure I tried to perform to obtain the Melvin metric using the dimensional reduction method and then magnetize the metric according to Gibbons' proposal in [this article in appendix A](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3927) . I would like you to take a look at it please