# Raising a solution to 4D after having dimensionally reduced it

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, compactification, kaluza-klein

I am applying the method that Gibbons presents in [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3927), and it consists of dimensionally reducing a four-dimensional Lagrangian using Kaluza Klein in $S_1$, to a three-dimensional one and after some calculations, applying a magnetic transformation to the three-dimensional Lagrangian , but I can't find information on how to raise this transformed three-dimensional Lagrangian to a four-dimensional one and find its metric. Does anyone know of any reference or book that explains how to raise a new lower dimensional solution to four dimensions? This question is a continuation of the discussion of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/797805/) other question I asked.